# Folders created with "Read Only" attribute and I cannot remove

Tags: windows-10

I have been having an issue with the read only flag on all of the folders on my system. I have tried checking my permissions and using console commands like

```
attrib -r c:\Foxfire\*.* /s
```

to try and reset the folders, but whenever I reset the folder it automatically resets to have the flag again.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are seeing is normal and the folders are not read only.

When used to show folder properties the Read-only checkbox has 3 states: checked, unchecked and a partially filled box. Folders will always show the latter state. This does not show that the folder is read-only. The text beside the checkbox says that it only applies to files in the folder. The checkbox is used to change the read-only state of the folders files, but not it's subfolders. If the checkbox is left in the default state no changes will be made.

In Windows Explorer listing some folders may show the read-only attribute. This does not mean the folder is read-only. It is used as a flag to tell Windows Explorer to check for the presence of a desktop.ini file. This file provides information as to how to display the folder, such as if it has a special icon.

Comment: Thanks for answer... I always wondered why Windows creates those apparently superfluous .ini files on Desktop and elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. Sorry for the delay in accepting!